# Multiple source files in Haskell

Tags: haskell, compilation, ghci

I'm writing my first big project in Haskell and I'd like to split it across multiple files. So far, I have written two modules, `Parse` and `Eval`. I'd like to have a `Main` module that just includes these two modules and specifies the `main` function. I have the files `Main.hs`, `Parse.hs`, and `Eval.hs` and import them in `Main`, but this happens:

```
Prelude> :load "~/code/haskell/lisp/Main.hs"
[1 of 3] Compiling Eval             ( Eval.hs, interpreted )
[2 of 3] Compiling Parse            ( Parse.hs, interpreted )
[3 of 3] Compiling Main             ( ~/code/haskell/lisp/Main.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main, Parse, Eval.
*Main> parse parseExpr "" "#b101"

<interactive>:1:0: Not in scope: `parse'
```

The `parse` function comes from Parsec library, which is imported in `Parse.hs`. What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Haskell report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/modules.html):

> A module implementation may only
>   export an entity that it declares, or
>   that it imports from some other
>   module. If the export list is omitted,
>   all values, types and classes defined
>   in the module are exported, *but not
>   those that are imported*.

You either need to give an explicit export list that includes `parse` in `Parse.hs`, or import `parse` again in your `Main.hs`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
module Parse (parse) where
    import qualified Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec as P

    parse = P.parse
```

But really, this is useless. You'll certainly be wanting to build something more domain-specific on top of Parsec before you export it from one of your modules.